# Is the specification of SIG_IGN's undefined behavior regarding SIGFPE, SIGILL, SIGSEGV redundant?

Tags: c, signals, posix, language-lawyer

POSIX.1-2017 specifies under [XSH 2.4.3 SIG_IGN](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03_02) that

> The behavior of a process is undefined after it ignores a SIGFPE, SIGILL, SIGSEGV, or SIGBUS signal **that was not generated by kill(), sigqueue(), or raise()**.

and I'm wondering what the significance of the emphasized part is?

Can you ignore those signals generated only by the above functions yet avoid invoking undefined behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't `SIG_IGN`-ore those signals if you're expecting the kernel to generate them.

You can catch them with `sigaction` and `SA_SIGINFO` in `.sa_flags` and use `SA_SIGINFO` so you can then use `info->si_code` in the handler to distinguish between kernel-sent and user-sent variants.
If you then do nothing in the handler if the signal wasn't kernel-sent and exit/abort if it was, then with a `SA_RESTART` handler you've basically got yourself a userspace emulation of `SIG_IGN` that also works with kernel-sent `SISGEV`, `SIGILL`, etc.

If you use real `SIG_IGN`, you must take care not to provoke the kernel into generating these signals (no invalid memory references, no invalid instructions, etc.).

I think POSIX allows you to safely ignore `SIGFPE`, `SIGILL`, `SIGSEGV`, or `SIGBUS` simply because there's no strong reason to flatly disallowing ignoring these signals in all circumstances, but I don't think there's much significance behind the feature otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, it says that if the signal is generated by the kernel as a result of a *hardware fault or trap*, then ignoring such a signal has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Indeed. But why make that distinction at all? I don't see any way that a process can ignore  `kill()`, `sigqueue()` and `raise()`-generated signals without being potentially exposed to that UB-invoking behavior. Is there any?

Comment: You can't. You can catch them and use SA_SIGINFO to distinguish between kernel-sent and user-sent variants of those signals, or, if you do use real SIG_IGN, you must take care not to provoke the kernel into generating those signals (no invalid memory references, not invalid instructions, etc.).

Comment: @nebel One could potentially reuse those signals for application specific purposes, but most software refrain from doing that to make life easier. But there are certain use cases that require applications to recover from these signals, like applications with just-in-time compilers can just fail a JIT function if it generated, say, `SIGFPE` but not crash the application.

Comment: @PSkocik I didn't know about `SA_SIGINFO` providing the relevant data to make that distinction for caught signals, thank you. Even then I can't see much usefulness in even a fully-conforming program (as in one that doesn't invoke hardware faults) setting `SIG_IGN` for these signals. Maybe for some POSIX API unit test that generates `SIGFPE` etc. itself?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin but then you wouldn't be setting them to the `SIG_IGN` action. And that, too, is pretty much undefined if you don't eventually call `abort()` on their capture I think: _The behavior of a process is undefined after it returns normally from a signal-catching function for a `SIGBUS`, `SIGFPE`, `SIGILL`, or `SIGSEGV` signal that was not generated by `kill()`, `sigqueue()`, or `raise()`._ So sadly even that is not portable use unless you return *abnormally*, whatever that may mean.

Comment: @nebel I think you're worrying too much about a feature that's not very important and is simply there because "why not allow it?".

Comment: @PSkocik True. If you turn your first comment into an answer I'll accept it. I've learned a little from this exchange, so thanks for bearing with me!

Answer (score 0):

The undefined nature of process behavior probably stems from the reason those signals are sent in the first place.

If you're dealing with a fake signal that was sent manually for some reason, then the kernel wasn't involved.

Conditions that cause the kernel to send those signals are also cases where the process effectively "voided the warranty" on being properly behaved.